# Service versus BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

Qual a diferença, no Android, entre Service e BroadcastReceiver?

- Quanto tempo um Service pode ficar executado (rodando)?
- Quanto tempo um BroadcastReceiver pode ficar executado (rodando)?
- Posso cria notificações via BroadcastReceiver ou apenas via Service?
- É uma boa prática (a pergunta anterior)?

Answer (score 4):

A documentação define [Serviço](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/guide/components/services.html) da seguinte forma:

> Um Service é um componente do aplicativo que pode realizar operações longas e não fornece uma interface do usuário. Outro componente do aplicativo pode iniciar um serviço e ele continuará em execução em segundo plano mesmo que o usuário alterne para outro aplicativo. Além disso, um componente poderá vincular-se a um serviço para interagir com ele e até estabelecer comunicação entre processos (IPC). Por exemplo, um serviço pode lidar com operações de rede, reproduzir música, executar E/S de arquivos, ou interagir com um provedor de conteúdo, tudo a partir do segundo plano.

Por sua vez um BroadcastReceiver é um componente que permite ser registado para receber eventos.
Todos os receptores registados para um evento são notificados pelo SO Android uma vez que este evento aconteça.

### Quanto tempo um Service pode ficar executado (rodando)?

Quando iniciado através de [startService()](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService%28android.content.Intent%29) o serviço permanecerá em execução até ser interrompido por conta própria com [stopSelf()](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopSelf%28%29) ou pelo componente que o iniciou, chamando [stopService()](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/content/Context.html#stopService%28android.content.Intent%29).

Quando iniciado através de [bindService()](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/content/Context.html#bindService%28android.content.Intent,%20android.content.ServiceConnection,%20int%29) ele ficará rodando enquanto houver clientes vinculados.

Um serviço pode ser destruído pelo SO quando a memória estiver baixa e precisar recuperar recursos do sistema.

### Quanto tempo um BroadCastReceiver pode ficar executado (rodando)?

Um BroadcastReceiver é iniciado pelo SO se ele for elegível para o evento lançado.

Um BroadcastReceiver é válido apenas para a duração da chamada ao método [OnReceive()](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive%28android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent%29)
Uma vez o código retornar desse método, o sistema considera o objecto concluído e não mais activo, podendo ser destruído pelo SO.

A documentação diz que após 10 segundos o *receiver* será bloqueado e poderá ser destruído.

### Posso cria notificações via BroadCastReceiver ou apenas via Service?

Se você está a referir-se às notificações(NotificationManager) que aparecem na área de notificação do dispositivo, sim, é até uma forma usual de utilização dos BroadcastReceiver.

Você pode fazer tudo o que quiser no método [onReceive()](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive%28android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent%29) desde que seja de forma síncrona<sup>(1)</sup>.
Como esse código corre na *main thread* não os use para processos longos.

### É uma boa prática (a pergunta anterior)?

Sim, como disse anteriormente, lançar notificações é uma forma usual de utilização dos BroadcastReceiver.

<sub>(1)Essa limitação pode ser evitada usado [registerReceiver (BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter, String broadcastPermission, Handler scheduler)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html?hl=pt-br#registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Handler))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Um service é um componente que executa ações de longo prazo em segundo plano, ele não apresenta uma interface para o usuário. Como exemplo você poderia criar um service que acessa uma certa API externa em busca de novos dados, ao constatar que existem atualizações seu service poderia fazer um [broadcast](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcasting) dos dados usando [`sendBroadcast`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#sendBroadcast(android.content.Intent)) (método de um parent class), sendo que nesse ponto entraria o `BroadcastReceiver`, que é a classe utilizada para "escutar" broadcasts gerados por chamadas de `sendBroadcast`.

Quanto ao resto:

1. Pelo tempo que for necessário. O service pode ser criado pela aplicação e executar continuamente por tempo indefinido, mesmo com ela parada (quando está aberta mas você está executando outra aplicação);
2. Também indefinidamente. Você pode registrar um por uma [`Activity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), nesse caso ele só executa enquanto a activity executar, ou então pelo manifest da aplicação, nesse caso ele executa de maneira independente da activity;
3. Como o próprio nome indica `BroadCastReceiver` ("Receptor de broadcasts") é utilizado para receber notificações e não envia-lás;
4. Não faz sentido ;(.