# Tarefa longa no BroadcastReceiver, erro: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: java, android

Quando executo uma tarefa (que geralmente exige uma `AsyncTask`) no `BroadcastReceiver`, ele me acusa o erro:

`erro: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`

Vi que não é uma boa prática uma `AsyncTask` dentro de uma `BroadcastReceiver`.

Então o mais indicado seria um `Service` ? Ou não tem a ver com o erro !?

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.i("lgg", "onReceive " + new Date());

        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            URL url = new URL("site.com");
            URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(5000);

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                content.append(line + "\n");
            }
            bufferedReader.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("lgg", "erro: " + e);
        }

        Log.i("lgg", "recebido: " + content);
    }
```

Comment: Mas ramaral, eu já testei a solução de ignorar, e a `AsyncTask` não é boa prática.

Comment: Um BroadcastReceiver não deve ser usado para executar tarefas longas. Veja esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/122267/2541), Você pode usar o BroadcastReceiver para lançar um serviço que execute a operação demorada.

Comment: vc nao pode executar conexão a internet na MainThread